# Multitenancy using the Java driver for Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Willing to use multi-tenancy by assigning a keyspace for each tenant using cassandra Java driver. However, it seems that the keyspace ([documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/object_mapper/creating/)) is an annotation when defining objects so it will be hard switching tenant depending on some users credential attributes.

In that case, is logic discrimination of data is unique solution by adding a tenant to the partitioning key?

PS: for example Hibernate offers 3 types of multitenancy [documentation hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not compulsory to use annotation based approach, cassandra java driver needs only host details to connect to cluster, after that you can run any query.  you can use a prepared query with specified keyspace. also you can create keyspace dynamically using java driver.